# Static field of taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a content type with a static field that I want to reference a specific TAX term.  When a new node is added, I want the term to default to a specific reference, and I don't want the author to change it.  I was thinking that a STATIC FIELD could work, but not sure how to hard code the term reference.

put another way, I want to Hard code the TAXONOMY term into a field of another node type.

any other ideas on how this would be done or alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative could be adding a regular term reference field that has the particular taxonomy term you want referenced set as the default value. Then in a hook_form_FORM_ID_alter call the node edit form for the specific content type and set the #access value to FALSE for that field.